# Responsibility for animals as human and does it undermine true equality?

Tags: ethics, metaphysics

I have been thinking lately, coming to an interesting point of view, which may not necessarily be mine (not yet sure about that), but still worth to talk about. Unfortunately, I came into heated discussions with some friends and thus, I'd like to explain to you guys, what I had in mind and ask for clarification, how this world view is called, to which specific topics its related and how I can educate myself more on that.

It starts with the example of a random boar unknowingly running towards a cliff. By deciding to intervene and saving the boar, wouldn't the human intervene with the natural flow, patronizing the boar or even nature itself? By acting upon that situation and saving the boar, disregarding the will of the boar to run into that direction, the human would think something like "I know better than you", which could translate to "I am better/more than you". By not intervening and letting the boar act upon its free will to interact with its surroundings, doesn't a human actually respect the boar more, as it's met on "equal terms"? I don't want this example to be mapped to humans and their children, as we live in a society, which implies a lot of responsibility between its members and - for me - is a whole other discussion. This question is about the relation between humans and animals and why we do NOT live in an actual societal relation to them.

**Isn't preventing a boar to run down a cliff somewhat arrogant, disregarding ethical reasons?**

To taper this idea even further to a broader problem: any living creature does interact with its environment, regardless of what it may be. If a monkey enters a street and is hit by a car, is it really our responsibility or wouldn't we patronize him by making efforts to prevent this? Just because something is human-made or because we invaded his territory, is it really our responsibility? By any means created, this environment is by fact his environment, which has always been subject to change, either inherently (trees die, vulcanoes erupt) or by other creatures acting within the ecosystem (swarm of birds eat away all fruits or termites kill a bunch of trees). We are just one of the many actors in the life of a monkey (a disruptive one for sure). Isn't for true equality of humans and animals necessary, to be treated with all due respect, letting animals make their own choices and adapt to their environment (us + what we've build), in order to become true peers within our "society"? Building nature reserves may preserve the current state of an area and its flora/fauna, but at the same time, "from above", humans arrogantly presume the right to decide about that, with no justification other than their intellect.

**Wouldn't letting animals take actual part in our society, roam cities freely and interact with us be the "more natural" way than putting them into nature reserves and freeze their state-of-the-art?**

If I imagine a world in 2000 years in 2 versions:

- We put animals in nature reserves, as they were always used to and manage to preserve them - those animals would live pretty much exactly as they did before in those reserves. No change, no participation in the actual world. For me, this feels like we would be locking them up in isolated Ghettos.
- We let animals pursue their own will out of curiosity (given people do not hunt or kill them unreasonably up to a critical point). Some animals probably won't survive, some would be very shy about humans, but some would start roaming the city and it would become as normal as seeing a raccoon in your town, to e.g. see a monkey. This feels like an actual good way of humans living in symbiosis with animals to me/the holder of the viewpoint.

I'm not saying let all animals die or we should not take care of them, of course there will always be a reason to save an animal from a certain situation, either one is personally affiliated with the animal itself or for altruistic reasons. But if we live in an actual society with those animals, the question of saving an animal naturally has more sides to it and there may be enough reason for saving the animal without being patronizing.

Do I mix different things here or does this make sense? How would you answer those two bold questions with the given context? What is this point of view called and what are related concepts/authors, I can search for to deepen my understanding and maybe reevaluated?

Comment: This reads like an opinion essay with a very general bottom line of “what do you think?” —Is there any chance you could pare this back to asking a single question as directly as possible?

Comment: This does seem to mix up the sentient status of animals with civilization's relationship to nature. It also misses the fact that in some places monkeys, cows, deer and other animals do mix freely with urban populations and are tolerated or even encouraged.

Comment: Isn't stopping a person from jumping off a bridge "arrogant" the same way? It is their "free will" after all. How about treating cancer? Isn't it "natural" to die from it? Who knows what the "natural flow" is, or what "God wants", intervening or not intervening. We are its part, so it is pointless to worry about "disrupting" it. Any intervention is "arrogant", "playing God", etc., if this "argument" worked the only way to behave would be to do nothing at all. And intervening when someone is not in full possession of relevant information and/or their faculties isn't a bad occasion to intervene.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try answering the bold questions.

> Isn't preventing a boar to run down a cliff somewhat arrogant, disregarding ethical reasons?

The basis for the question sort of treats human beings as being separate from nature, but I understand that you are questioning *why* it is that we treat ourselves that way. This question is a part of a larger ethical quagmire that is difficult to rationalize. Consider this as an alternative:

A person witnesses a predator trapping prey (it could be any animal, but since we're trying to throw out bias let's say it's a spider and a butterfly). Which is more ethical, setting the butterfly free, potentially starving the spider, or letting the course unfold on its own?

Setting the butterfly free, whether it outright involves killing the spider or not, is disrupting the natural order, however that only applies if you treat human beings as being separate from nature. We exist within nature and affect just as any other living being. The big difference is we can contemplate that relationship, but that doesn't divorce us from it. If it is a matter of respect, it doesn't matter if we save the butterfly or not, simply regarding it as a fellow living organism is enough.

> Wouldn't letting animals take actual part in our society, roam cities freely and interact with us be the "more natural" way than putting them into nature reserves and freeze their state-of-the-art?

At first glance this looks like a "humans-as-nature" vs "humans-apart-from-nature" dichotomy, but really this is a question of how human society should function. There are many societies where animals exist freely among human beings. Granted, those societies are typically "poor" societies. We also have to recognize that human beings are a unique species which has the fate of every other species in their hands. That brings a lot of responsibility to humans as stewards of nature (who also are a part of nature). Simply put, the nature of humanity's relationship with other species is dynamic and it changes with every technological advancement. What way is more "natural" is really a comparison of old traditions and new responsibility.